# Laravel eloquent destroy over a 1001 records

Tags: laravel, eloquent, destroy

I am sending to my controller a matrix with more than 1000 IDs (2,540), after executing the destroy method of the medelo, this is working perfectly when processing less than 1000 records, above this the records are not erased, leaving records.
  I'm using softdelete in this model, why does it partially delete the records, leaving the residue above 1000 records?

Comment: Do you know what the actual query being executed is? If you can get that from a profiling tool or query log that would help a lot.

Comment: we need tos ee code

Comment: Sending to controller array:
`listRecordsDell = ['1','2', etc...] ` , Arrray 2500 itens.

In Controller:

`$clientsDeleteList = $request->input('listRecordsDell');`
`Client::destroy($clientsDeleteList);`

Comment: This format has been working perfectly until reaching 1000 records, after ignoring all records.

Comment: If you try running that with Laravel Debugbar installed that should tell you what the actual query is.

Comment: have you checked that [Laravel actually iterates every item one-by-one](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L737) for deleting an array of items? this one might hit php maximum execution time or memory limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full proof solution but this is a patch like divide your array list in chunks of 1000 using array_chunk() than write a for loop logic to execute the number of array list which you get from array_chunk() and call destroy method for them. I hope this is a quick fix till you install any debuggar and do the debugging.

Comment: OK, for now I'll be implementing the solution indicated by my friend Hamza Dairywala. Thank you all.